# Sql server how to create new role with Transact-SQL

Tags: sql-server

I know we can create new role with Transact-SQL with docs: `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187936.aspx`， but it only support 2012+ version. How about Sql Server 2008, 2005, I can't create role with SQL Server Management Studio, because I need to create it with python code.

Answer (score 0):

I was a little confused as you asked how to create a new role using T-SQL then said you can't use SSMS as you needed to create the role using Python?

The T-SQL to create a new Role as taken from the MSDN documents actually works in 2008+

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
CREATE ROLE buyers AUTHORIZATION BenMiller;  
GO
```

Comment: in fact, only 2012+ version of sql server can create custom role. 2008 can't